# Batch file to change Desktop background

Tags: windows-7, batch

I want to write a batch file that changes the Desktop background.

This is what I have so far:

```
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d   C:\background.jpg
Reg Add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10
```

The first line works and changes the picture. But the 2nd line does not work.

I'm not sure what the `/v /f /t /d` switches mean.

Is there something wrong the my 2nd line?

Comment: Run reg add /? to see what those all mean.

Comment: oh okay so then all of those are valid but it is still not changing the style to fill which is what the 10 should be

Comment: Well, I can't promise anything but when I searched on WallpaperStyle etc. I found this http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2011/03/best-practice-using-group-policy-to-configure-desktop-wallpaper-background/ which says among other things that it won't work until the user logs off and back on.

Comment: Ive been restarting after i run the script

Comment: -1 you've made no attempt at troubleshooting.. e.g. see if it has written to the registry and see if making that change in the registry changes the wallpaper

Answer (score -1):

```
echo off
call :quiet>nul 2>&1
goto :EOF
:quiet

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d %windir%:\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10

:: Make the changes effective immediately
:: %SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

This works!

Comment: Where's the difference to what the OP already posted? Your last line which is commented out?

Answer (score -1):

You can download the batch file with the correct code here:

https://mega.nz/file/ra4AECKC#uivKImmOZmowf39Sow9Un-zAqWsPcGXTk2xsoc4Qv5M

You must edit the file a little. You must change the ENTER PICTURE PATCH HERE to the full patch of the picture.

Sorry for any bad English.

Comment: Could you address how this is superior to the other answer? That is using the registry and yours in changing files.